# Formulation of percentage difference

Tags: percentage

I have calculated true positive rate (TPR) for two tests. I want to report the % difference for test b compared to test a. This is very simple, however, I have gotten myself confused as to how to report this.

Example:
TPR for test a = 38/110 = 34.5%.
TPR for test b = 45/110 = 40.9%.

Which (if any) of the following statements are correct?

**1.** 40.9%-34.5% = 6.4%: “Test b showed a higher proportion of detected diseases by 7 (+6.4%)”.

**2.** (45/38)/38 = 3.1%: “Test b showed a higher proportion of detected diseases by 7 (+3.1%)”.

**3.** 100 * ((|38-45|)/(38+45)) /2 = 16.9%: “Test b showed a higher proportion of detected diseases by 7 (+16.9%)”.

I hope you can help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of popular contrasts for binary data.  I'll illuminate two of them you seem to be getting at.

### Risk Difference

The risk difference is literally the difference in rates between groups.  If $p_1 = 38/110$ and $p_2 = 45/110$ then the risk difference is

$$ p_2 - p_1 \approx 0.064 $$

I would say something like "Group 2 had a risk 6.4 percentage points higher than group 1".  The use of percentage points makes it clear you're talking about an absolute difference.

### Risk Ratio

The risk ratio is literally the ratio between risks, i.e.

$$ \dfrac{p_2}{p_1} = \dfrac{45/110}{38/110} \approx 1.18  $$

I would say something like "The rate in group 2 had a relative difference over group 1 of 18%".  Here, the use of the word "relative" communicates you're talking about differences relative to group 1.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't so simple as you might have hoped. Any of those choices is subject to mis-interpretation by your readers, precisely because of the difficulty you have in making this choice.

Expressing values in percents and percentage changes too often ends up being confusing rather than clarifying. See for example this [post by Frank Harrell](https://www.fharrell.com/post/percent/).

The simplest solution and the one least likely to lead to confusion: let the results speak for themselves, and avoid any invocation of percents. For example, "TPR for test `a` was 0.34. TPR for test `b` was 0.41." It would be best to include error estimates around those point estimates.